# Trouble with Plotly line chart from Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I'm trying to plot a line chart from a mysql table (utf-8), but every time I try it in Plotly, the plot zigzags. It looks as if it is reading the datetime field as a string when it plots. However, as you can see in the screenshot both axes and point labels are correct. Also, I get no errors. I have tried to format, encode, convert, etc and I can't get it to work. Here's the code:

```
nflx = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT ticker,date(pubDate) as pubDate,sentimentScore FROM targets', engine, parse_dates=['pubDate'])
nflx.head()

ticker    pubDate    sentimentScore
0    NFLX    2017-01-09    0.84
1    NFLX    2017-01-09    -0.59
2    NFLX    2017-01-09    -0.50
3    NFLX    2017-01-09    0.00
4    NFLX    2017-01-09    0.67


nflx.iplot(x='pubDate', y='sentimentScore')
```

I don' get any errors but the plot comes out like this:

plotly line chart gone haywire

[image]

Comment: @eyllanesc why the downvote? I'm fairly new to SO but put in as much detail as I think necessary into the question. I noticed you were able to add the screenshot into into question. SO policy doesn't let noobs post images until they get a certain amount of whatever.

Comment: I have not done any downvote, just edit your question.

Comment: Downvotes are not not for showing pictures, they are usually given by questions that have little information, or that the author writes things like frustration, problems, etc., instead of focusing on the question.

Comment: That you are new does not imply that you do not ask good questions, for this you must pass the tour, besides that you win a medal, you could read how it is asked, as it is answered, the rules of SO.

Comment: Understood. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy enough fix, sort your dates:

```
nflx.sort_values(by='pubDate')\
    .iplot(x='pubDate', y='sentimentScore')
```

Comment: After restoring DATETIME format to the MySQL query, sorting the dates fixed the issue.